# My code isn't working, i have no errors and looks perfectly fine

Tags: java

Ok so no matter what I input of the second guess it says its higher than 60 but its not, this may be a rookie error but I can't understand why? If someone can run this fix up the errors and explain what wen't wrong it would be a great help

```
package testing;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class testerclass {
    public static void main (String args[]){
        double user1ans, user2ans, total, number, guess1, guess2, count, diff1, diff2;
        Random dice = new Random();
        Scanner user1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner user2 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter player one's guess: ");
        guess1 = user1.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter player two's guess: ");
        guess2 = user2.nextInt();
        if (guess1 > 60 || guess2 > 60);
            System.out.println("You can't guess higher than 60!");
            testerclass.main(args);
        for (count=1; count<=10; count++){
            number = dice.nextInt(6+1);
            total = number + number;
            System.out.println(number);
            System.out.println(total);
        user1ans = guess1 - total;
        user2ans = guess2 - total;
        if (user1ans == 0 && user2ans == 0);
            System.out.println("Its a draw!");
            testerclass.main(args);
        if (user1ans == 0);
            System.out.println("Player one wins!!");
            testerclass.main(args);
        if (user2ans == 0);
            System.out.println("Player two wins!!");
            testerclass.main(args);
        if (user1ans == user2ans && user2ans == user1ans);
            System.out.println("Its a draw!!");
            testerclass.main(args);
        diff1 = Math.abs(guess1 - total);
        diff2 = Math.abs(guess2 - total);
        if (diff1 < diff2);
            System.out.println("Player one wins");
            testerclass.main(args);
        if (diff2 < diff1);
            System.out.println("Player two wins");
            testerclass.main(args);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest (i) write the code (ii) test that it works as expected (iii) if it doesn't, ask a question describing what is not working...

Comment: Why don't you write the code (you can do it you say) and check if it works?

Comment: Read a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). I'd recommend reading it from the start, but I pointed you to the particular tutorial that talks about this.

Comment: All your 'if's are wrong. And don't indent your code yourself, let your IDE do that. Since you indeted your code wrong, you're not noticing the problems.

Comment: After your edit: Java is not Python. Indentation does not make the code belong to the `if`. The only part that belongs to the `if` is, if there are curly braces after the condition, the part in the curly braces, and if not, the part up to the first `;`. Now check where your first `;` is.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Don't use 2 Scanners, one is enough :) (As you are reading the input from only one source - a single command line)

(2) In your first for-loop the second line should be "total = total + number" (?)
(3) Also, you will need a difference, so wrap `guess1 - total` and `guess2 - total` in `Math.abs()`:

```
user1ans = Math.abs(total - guess1);
user2ans = Math.abs(total - guess2)
```

(4) All commands / functions inside a `if` should be in a body (example of a "good" if):

```
if(STATEMENT)
{
   // Things to do go here
}
```

Because otherwise (like in your code) it will execute the code regardless wether the if-statement is true or false (because there's a `;` after your `if`)

(5) I would also suggest copying the whole code in a new function and call `return;` instead of `testerclass.main(args)`.

---

(I know, I shouldn't do it, but here, the final code)

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * Created by cyphrags on 28.04.15.
 */
public class test
{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        while(true)
        {
            GuessIt();
        }
    }

    public static void GuessIt()
    {
        double user1ans, user2ans, total = 0, number, guess1, guess2, count, diff1, diff2;

        Random dice = new Random();

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter player one's guess: ");
        guess1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter player two's guess: ");
        guess2 = in.nextInt();

        if (guess1 > 60 || guess2 > 60) {
            System.out.println("You can't guess higher than 60!");
            return;
        }

        for (count=1; count<=10; count++) {
            number = dice.nextInt(6 + 1);
            total = number + number;
            //System.out.println(number);
            //System.out.println(total);
        }

        System.out.println(total);

        user1ans = Math.abs(guess1 - total);
        user2ans =  Math.abs(guess2 - total);

        if (user1ans == user2ans) {
            System.out.println("Its a draw!");
        } else if (user1ans < user2ans) {
            System.out.println("Player one wins!!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Player two wins!!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah the draw would be handy, this is why I am stuck because finding out the difference to find which one is bigger just confuses me and yes I just realised I won't need two totals thanks :)

Comment: Cheers for your help I will comment my code after im done just for you to check, I think ive gone a slightly different way around it but it should work appreciate the help :)

Comment: Heres my code, and its not working but it seems fine if I enter and input in the second input it says its higher than 60

Comment: So here the final code :) (Tested it, should work) Make sure to read up on `bodies` for functions, loops etc. because like RealSkeptic mentioned your code looks very similar to python.